# Regex to grab all <,> not a part of an XML tag

Tags: regex, xml

I have an XML file with a bunch of `<`, `>` characters, accidentally, and I need to replace them with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.  What kind of regex can select `<`,`>`, and ignore any string of the form `<[any word]>`?  It may not be possible, if so, regex that just ignores strings of the form `<Abstract>` are also great.

Thanks

Comment: is the regex formatted with a single line being a single element?

Comment: What language do you want to use for the regex? Some regex engines won't handle true recursion

Comment: Please don't call it XML if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as a good start: `/<(?![a-z\/])|(?<![a-z])>/g`.

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/YPNEMU/1.

It will actually match every occurence of `<` and `>` that are not directly preceded by a letter or followed by either a letter or `/`.

Now remain to match also if just next to a letter but missing opening or closing the tag!

---

**[EDIT] improve regex**

This one goes further with matching also `<` occurences that are directly followed by a letter but non closing tag: `/<(?![a-z\/][a-z\/ ]*?>)|(?<![a-z])>/g`

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/YPNEMU/2

---

**[EDIT] best solution**

I found it using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`!

`/(<[a-z\/][^<>]*?>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[<>]/g`.

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/YPNEMU/3